# Accessing Outbound Mails

Tags: email, apex-email-service

I would like to access the outbound emails sent from salesforce to the users(for eg. notification mail, scheduled reports mails etc). Could anyone tell me where those mails will be stored in the salesforce and how to access those mails using apex?

Thanks
Raghu

Answer (score 2):

You can access details about email logs from within the administration interface from Admin > Monitoring > Email Logs.

This will not show you the email body however, just the recipient and delivery status.

The Compliance BCC email mentioned by Barney Rubble is the other option to be cc'd on future emails.

You may also find the messages you want in the 'EmailMessage' object which will contain the emails sent from within the UI (Case responses).  I'm not sure if other emails sent from the UI will appear there.  Emails sent from Workflow etc shouldn't appear in this object.

Other than that I am not aware of there being any other way to retrieve email content of emails sent by the system.

Answer (score 1):

You can BCC all Salesforce outbound emails to any email address. The feature is called **Compliance BCC Emails**.

Setup => Email Administration => Compliance BCC Email

http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/admin_compliancebcc.htm

New user notification emails, password resets emails, etc., are not BCC-ed using this feature.

Comment: hi, i want to access the emails that are already sent. could you please let me know if there is any such way