# Where are my attachements?

Tags: email, attachment

I clicked the Send Email button on the Activities related list present on the Case object. While sending the mail, I also attached an image to the mail. While I receive the attachment in the email address specified, I am not able to locate the same attachment in salesforce. Also the email that I sent appears in the description/comments field of the task. I checked the Task attachments but I could not find them

Any idea, where these attachments are stored? If it is not possible to locate them in the Salesforce UI, fine; can I get them by issuing a query to some object?

Answer (score 3):

"It's not a bug, it's a feature."

As annoying as it is, they do it on purpose to protect us from exhausting our file storage space (you would either have to periodically wipe out attachments or keep buying more space).

http://success.salesforce.com/questionDetail?qid=a1X30000000JN2YEAW
http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/Attachment-used-in-email-template-is-not-saved/td-p/282245

And idea to upvote: http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000bEDlAAM

If you really want to capture attachments - you need to write some code.

1. Create an [inbound email service](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_inbound_using.htm) that'd be analyzing "To" address, searching for Case number in email's subject etc.
2. Put the address in BCC field of your email (you'd have to do it manually every time though; painful because the email address is not user friendly). Maybe create a custom button that'd be prepopulating the BCC field for you.
3. Or use the trick with "Compliance" email address, see [Accessing Outbound Mails](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8237/accessing-outbound-mails) for details.

Comment: can you elaborate on #2? when the user selects an email template, is there a way to prepopulate the bcc?

Comment: @nivyaj just on email template selection - not much you can do. But Standard URL hacks are fine. Create a custom button / link to send emails and use `p5=example@example.com` in that the address. Not ideal but it's something. See http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17780/mail-merge-button too (if you want to let user specify the template it's of course fine too, nobody says you have to specify template_id)